# How to get the signature of a method which is inside a Interface?

Tags: java, jar, signature, javap

I have a class named Fruits. Inside the class there is a interface named Sour. Inside the Interface I have a method GetItems();

```
public class Fruits
{
    ----------------
    ----------------
    public interface Sour
    {
        public int GetItems();
    }
}
```

How to get the signature of the GetItems() method?. I want to use this signature in JNI GetMethodID method.

Comment: Where are you trying to get this from?  In Java code you can use reflection to get `Method` object representing your method - and then use it to reconstruct the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Some class has to first implement that interface.

Once a class has imlpemented an interface then you should be able to get the methodID for the interface method, which is now a member of the class that implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JNI without a class implementing your Interface. Just use the signature of this implementing class.